# synchronization of more data, than available online storage

Tags: sync

If I have more than 5GB data to synchronize between computers, will Ubuntu One be still synchronizing it all correctly between computers, or will I have to upgrade my account? I do not necessarily need all my data available online.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to sync only between your computers. That might become an option in the future though. In other words; presently, you need to upgrade your Ubuntu One account.